# jquery-based HTML5 forms validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, html

I am searching for a jquery-based validation library which becomes active if the browser isn't HTML5 compliant for the particular attribute (e.g. 'required', 'placeholder', etc).  I've searched and found numerous libraries but either they aren't yet production-quality or, as is the case with the default JQuery Validation library, they don't follow the HTML5 syntax;  they use classes instead of attributes to specify the rules.   I want my HTML to be natively compatible with the new browsers so that validation library in particular doesn't meet the requirements.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery Validate added [improved HTML5 support](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/commit/b8801490d42807c901767761bffdf52d3e2ecf57) last week. In particular, you can use the required attribute and HTML5 types instead of using the class attribute.